# Preencher um Checked List Box com valores do SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Eu estou criando um formulário que gostaria que funcionasse da seguinte forma:
Primeiro o usuário selecionaria o tipo de exercício que seria jogado na Checked list Box utilizando um Combo Box, então o banco retornaria todos os valores encontrados que batessem com aquele tipo de exercício (Por exemplo o usuário escolheria Costas na ComboBox e apareciam todos os exercícios para costas na Checked List Box).

Eu sei como exibir os valores em um Data Grid, mas por quesito estético e pelo funcionamento final do formulário eu prefiro não usar Data Grid.

```cs
            Conexao.Conectar();
            string sql = @"select Exer_NM from Exercicios  
                          Where Exer_Tipo = @Exer_Tipo";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conexao.conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Exer_Tipo", cboTipo.Text);

            // Armazena o resultado do comando SELECT
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Laço de repetição para retornar todos os valores
           // dr.Read() - Lê uma nova linha
            while (dr.Read())
            {
              //  Mostra no listBox os dados retornados
                clb.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());


            }
            Conexao.Desconectar();
```

Minhas maiores dúvidas são:

1 - No código que tentei montar, se estou utilizando o evento correto (ComboBox Selected Index Changed ou deveria usar o Text Changed por exemplo.

2 - Se é correto atribuir o parametro "Exer_Tipo" para o cboTipo.text.

3 - E se há algum erro gigantesco no meu código.

(Estou usando o Sql Server 2017, eu postei o código em imagem porque não estou habituado com a formatação de texto do site ainda, peço desculpas se isso dificulta a compreensão).

Comment: coloque o código na pergunta ao invés de uma imagem

Comment: Mesmo que não saiba formatar o código no site, insira-o no lugar da imagem, alguém fará a formatação pra você.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei o código. Usei como base um codigo para adicionar numa listbox os valores que foram encontrados no Select.

Answer (score 0):

O select eu uso assim
@"select Exer_NM from Exercicios 
Where Exer_tipo =  @Exer_tipo" 
(sem aspas simples no parâmetro entendeu?)

O método 
Cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@Excer_tipo", cboTipo.Text); 
Vc tem q colocar o @ antes do Excer_tipo
Blz?
Vc pode usar este mesmo evento ou o OnValueChenge ou similar, mas tbm vc pode usar o evento validated, que executa quando o comboBox perde o foco

Seria bom vc usar o clb.items.Clear() no início do evento
Para que o listBox seja lipo sempre antes de ser adicionado outro itens